# Using Pashua with bash

Tags: bash

I'm using a bash script in OSX with [Pashua](https://www.bluem.net/pashua-docs-latest.html) to create a GUI popup

```
PASH="/Applications/Pashua.app/Contents/MacOS/Pashua"
CONF="/Users/user1/desktop/pashconf.pash"
$PASH $CONF
```

The config file is:

```
tb.type = textbox
tb.default = Line 1[return]Line 2[return]Line 3
tb.width = 300
tb.height = 60
tx.type = textfield
tx.label = Example textfield
tx.default = Textfield content
tx.width = 310
```

This outputs:

```
tx=Textfield content
tb=Line 1[return]Line 2[return]Line 3
tx=Textfield content
tb=Line 1[return]Line 2[return]Line 3
```

But I'd like to use all the variables and arrays in the output as bash variables. What's the best method for doing this?

Also - Is it possible to put the config code inside the bash script?

Many thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with `pashua` so fwiw ... 1) does `pashua` really generate 2 sets of identical rows as output or is that a typo? 2) how would you expect that output to be represented as `bash` variables, ie, what would be the equivalent `bash` variable names and contents?

Comment: Hi Mark sorry for delay in replying. 1) Yes that is indeed a typo. 2) I would like the variables to be converted to bash variables, so tx would be converted to $tx in bash, and when calling echo $tx in bash it would output "Textfield content".

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick. It stores a single returned value as a variable and contains the conf information in the script.

```
# App path
PASH="/Applications/Pashua.app/Contents/MacOS/Pashua"
# Conf file path
CONF="/tmp/conf.pash"

# Create a temp conf file
rm $CONF
cat <<EOT >> $CONF
tf.type = textfield
tf.label = Example textfield
tf.default = Textfield content
tf.width = 310
tf.tooltip = This is an element of type “textfield”
EOT

# Run Pashua and store the variable
VAR=$($PASH $CONF | cut -d '=' -f2)

echo $VAR
```